# java.io.IOException: Unable to open sync connection! in to the Nexus

Tags: android, ioexception

I try my application run on eclipse but i found these errors. which is faced first time so would you please give me any ideas for these error. i am currently using Nexus mobile.

```
  [2011-08-04 15:59:09 - App] Android Launch!
  [2011-08-04 15:59:09 - App] adb is running normally.
  [2011-08-04 15:59:09 - App] Performing  com.horror.android.AppActivity     activity launch
  [2011-08-04 15:59:09 - App] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'HT9CRP800333'
  [2011-08-04 15:59:09 - App] Uploading Test.apk onto device 'HT9CRP800333'
  [2011-08-04 15:59:09 - App] Failed to install Test.apk on device 'HT9CRP800333': Unable to open sync connection!
  [2011-08-04 15:59:09 - App] java.io.IOException: Unable to open sync connection!
  [2011-08-04 15:59:09 - App] Launch canceled!
```

Why i am getting ***java.io.IOException: Unable to open sync connection!*** .
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you want more solution about this problem clich this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912548/android-adb-unable-to-open-sync-connection

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No it is not about your code.
Try to plug usb out and than plag it in again. If it is not help try to reboot you device. Usually it works for me in such cases.

Comment: I am still faced this problem.

Comment: Here I found the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912548/android-adb-unable-to-open-sync-connection

Comment: reboot zindabaad  - thats hindi for "Long live reboot" :D

Answer (score 49):

get into Settings->Development->, and try disabling 'USB debugging' and enabling the same

Comment: this works well - is faster than rebooting!

Comment: Seems to be really the best solution.

Comment: [There's a nifty app that does this.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixplicity.adb) Unfortunately it requires root, but it's especially handy on my SGS2 since I have to unplug the cable, plug it in again, close the USB mount window and head through the menu a second time.

Answer (score 4):

**From Your Computer:**

Try restarting ADB:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

For Linux(I have to do this on Ubuntu):

```
sudo -i (for root)
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Script I made in my '.bashrc':

```
alias fixadb="sudo sh -c '/path/to/adb kill-server'; sudo sh -c '/path/to/adb start-server';"
```

For Windows:

```
Ctrl + Alt + Del - Open Task Manager
Kill adb.exe
Right-click on adb.exe, Run as Administrator
```

USB Ports:

```
Try switching USB ports, this usually helps me every once in a while.
```

**From your Phone:**

Android SDK < 11:

```
Settings > Development > Try disabling and re-enabling 'USB debugging'
```

Android SDK > 11:

```
Settings > Developer Options > Try disabling and re-enabling 'Android debugging'
```

Try restarting your phone