# Android studio adb failing (non sense !!?)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

Android studio emulator is failing on my machine and I have no idea what else I can do. I have tried the solutions on these two links : 
[Android device is not connected to USB for debugging (Android studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509422/android-device-is-not-connected-to-usb-for-debugging-android-studio)
[java.io.IOException: Unable to open sync connection! in to the Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939741/java-io-ioexception-unable-to-open-sync-connection-in-to-the-nexus)

So to sum up here's what I did :

1- Downloaded Android Studio from the official website then I installed it.
(While installing I installed also Intel® HAXM)

2- I installed Android SDK API (15, 16, 19, 21, 23) plus Java JDK + JRE version 8u92 (I also set JAVA_HOME to JDK folder path and included it to the PATH variable also)

3- Dowloaded and installed google usb drivers from http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top  (by the way my phone is totally recognized by my Windows 7 OS)

4- Made an "Hello world program" according to https://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html

5- Enabled USB debboging mode on my cell phone (Alcatel Mpop One touch ; Jelly Bean 4.1.1)

6- Switched between the 3 modes ; PTP, MTP, USB... nothing happened...

Is it me or Android studio is NOT reliable...it seems it should work smoothly just by enabling usb debogging ont the phone. Still I get **NO USB device or running emulator running**

How can I fix this ? Or is there an alternative to adb of android studio to test my apps on my phone (with installing the app on the phone...) ?

Comment: Is your device recognized by ADB? Open a cmd line, input `adb list` (You may have to add ADB to your path env before.)

Comment: @J.Dow  Nope. I think the correct command is `adb devices` or `adb forward --list` I tried those (yours not a command see here --> http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). It seems adb is not detecting my device AT ALL

Comment: Some USB cables only work for charging the device

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this [adbDriver](http://adbdriver.com/) it works for me on Samsung J1 and Galaxy Star Duos pro

Comment: nope not working. Though I see one thing now. One driver is not recognized. It's my telephone company driver on my phone that is ot recognized. BUT windows is able to see my phone and I can access it BUT the telephone company seems to have installed some driver on the Phone... hmm Now I'm starting to think I need to manually reinstall android OS to get rid of these things ...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

Finally after weeks of searching the internet, I think my problem is related to a missing driver. Though I'm not quite sure why.

The missing driver is a driver from my Telephony service company (Orange.fr in my case). I suppose they made changes to the Android OS / the pohne itself.. anyways there is one of their driver missing.

NEVER BUY A PHONE FROM a telecommunications services company. Always get it from the manufacturer in unlocked mode...that's the lesson I get from this.